# Php is using universal time and not local time

Tags: php, apache

All my timestamp from php are wrong because its using universal time and not local time which is for me Europe/Paris

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Paris'
Local time is now:      Wed Jun 25 14:57:37 CEST 2014.
Universal Time is now:  Wed Jun 25 12:57:37 UTC 2014.

An idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Set timezone in your script

Comment: Please provide a compelling test script. You may be telling us one thing, but your code may be doing something else.

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_default_timezone_set();` to set a default timezone for your code.

For example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
// Use date() or other functions now.
```

Anyways - **Google is your friend**

Answer (score 0):

```
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));

$date_format = $date->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```